# Android - Get text and validating it from EditTextPreference

Tags: android, edittextpreference

I am implementing a Preference where users enter and save a PIN number. I am using an `EditTextPreference` for that and the PIN number should exactly be 4 digits. In order to validate it, I used the following `OnPreferenceChangeListener()` method

```
final EditTextPreference pinRetrieve = (EditTextPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("create_pin");

pinRetrieve.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
                Boolean rtnval = true;
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pinRetrieve.getText())){
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.pin_error_heading);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.pin_alert_pin_not_set);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.show();
                    pinSetting.setChecked(false);
                    rtnval = false;

                } else if (pinRetrieve.getText().length() < 4){
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.pin_error_heading);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.pin_alert_pin_less_digits);
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.show();
                    pinSetting.setChecked(false);
                    rtnval = false;
                }
                return rtnval;
            }
        });
```

Even when I enter 4 digits, I am getting the alert box with `R.string.pin_alert_pin_not_set` as the message, what I think happening is it always goes to `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pinRetrieve.getText()))`, even when it is not empty.

Can't I use `TextUtils.isEmpty(pinRetrieve.getText())` on `EditBoxPreference`? If I can why does it always return true even when the `pinRetrieve.getText()` is not empty?

Thank you

Comment: why should your editextpreference be final ?

Comment: Tried removing the final. Then AndroidStudio says I can't use `EditBoxPreference` in the inner class `onPreferenceChange ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter passed to `onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o)` is the new Value of the preference you can check that instead of using the `EditTextPreference` reference. You will also be able to drop the `final` keyword. And get rid of the warnings. All you need is cast the `o` value to a String. If your preferences are added from an xml file you can add an `android:maxLength="4"` attribute - this will not allow the user to type in more than 4 characters in the EditText.

Comment: Thank you :) `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(o.toString()))` is finally working.

Answer (score 0):

The isEmpty function of TextUtils class accepts a char sequence as an argument and the getText of EditTextPreferences returns a string.

Rather try

```
(TextUtils.isEmpty(new CharSequence(pinRetrieve.getText())))
```

String implements the CharSequence interface.

You can try to use the subsequence function of the string class and it will return a charsequence.

```
String pin = pinRetrievce.getText();
CharSequnce pinSequence = pin.subSequence(0, pin.length());
(TextUtils.isEmpty(pinSequence)
```

Comment: Tried it thanks. But it says `charSequence is abstract and cannot be instantiated` :(

Comment: You can use String pinSequence = pin.subSequence(0, pin.length()).toString();